# Nomi siciliani glossario per oggetti

Tags: word-meaning, regional, nouns

Ciao,

Sto facendo una ricerca su dei documenti Latini ma ci sono alcune parole in Siciliano Medievale. C'è un glossario di queste parole, come ad esempio "dublecti" che significa "gonna"?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: Non sono sicura che questa domanda si possa considerare [on-topic](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31/are-questions-about-dialects-on-topic).

Comment: Mi dispiace per l'OP, ma ritengo anch'io che sia off-topic: il siciliano – per non parlare poi di quello medievale – è una lingua diversa dall'italiano.

Answer (score 1):

Non esiste proprio un "Siciliano Medievale", ma piuttosto nel medioevo in Sicilia si parlavano lingue siculo-arabe, normanne o gallo-italiche ([Lingua siciliana](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingua_siciliana) su Wikipedia).

Per quanto riguarda la parola "*dublecti*" in Sicilia è attestata nella veste latineggiante *dubletum* già nel
1308, poi nella forma *dubbrettu*, veste femminile. La presenza
contemporanea della voce anche nel calabrese *dubbrettu* e napoletano *rubretto* permette di ipotizzare un'origine del termine nel periodo normanno.

Attraverso i dialetti meridionali, in particolare il napoletano, la voce passa all'italiano antico *dobletto*, panno di Napoli di lino e bambagia tessuto al modo francese (da [I normanni in Inghilterra e in Sicilia](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/80167171.pdf)).